# Error 404 not going after Wordpress Permalink change to custom structure

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, runtime-error, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I am having a lot of problem because error 404 is not going. I have changed the permalinks to /%postname%/ . Since then I am getting 404 when I try to move to any page other than "Home". Home works fine.

Website : http://www.jitechnologies.com (The website is built by a non-professional, so please ignore the design for now). Website is hosted and the hosting company does not allow me to edit the web.config file. So please suggest your resolution accordingly.

I have checked the .htaccess code several times and here it is for your reference:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have removed all plug-ins.
I changed the permalink structure to "Default" then everything works perfectly. but, /%postname%/ again I start getting 404 Errors.

Is there something I am missing out. I request some technical help for this resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697061/wordpress-post-name-permalinks-not-working?

Comment: I have tried all the steps describes in that post. Could not resolve.

Comment: Please show us the content of your `web.config` file. As you are running on IIS, `.htaccess` is not available to you. You also state that you cannot change `web.config` - how can that be true? If the file is in your application root, then you should be able to edit it. If not, it is a permissions issue that needs to be resolved. A hosting company should not deny you access to that file as it is essential to so many applications.

Comment: I also refer you to the WordPress documentation regarding permalinks on IIS: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite

Comment: @MikeRockett thanks for your response. I have my hosting account on godaddy and they say that permission cannot be granted to edit web.config file. They also say that web.config has nothing to do with my problem.
 Though I will again connect to godaddy tomorrow for permission to edit web.config file.
I have read the documentation and all my links and settings are as per the documentation.
So may I ask you if this is a web.config issue and rest everything is OK as per your knowledge?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you need only use the prescribed `web.config` from the WP Codex. GoDaddy must allow you to use that file. Also, they shouldn't state it has nothing to do with your problem because WordPress requires for permalinks, and they're not letting you modify it. I don't host with Windows, but I imagine you'd be able to change the access permissions yourself...

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem before and it was because I didn't upload wordpress to the root folder of my domain. Make sure it is. If that doesn't work, clear the cookies in your browser. If that doesn't work, create a backup of your database through your cPanel and then re-install Wordpress making *sure* it is in the correct root folder on your domain. Without seeing everything you are talking about, it is hard to say for sure, but I am sure it doesn't have anything to do with your web.config file.

If you do all of these things and re-install wordpress, it should work just fine. Again, this sounds like the exact same thing that happened to me about a year ago, so give it a try. If that doesn't work it must be your permissions.. Check the 'all permissions' box when you create your new database from your cPanel if everything else has still failed. This means you will be starting from scratch essentially, but wordpress has so many good features, this shouldn't be such a terrible thing.